# how do I create a calculated field that returns days remaining till end of FISCAL_QUARTER?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[Current output with no DAYS_LEFT_IN_QUARTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTgmY.png)I am new to using Snowflake and was tasked to create a Calendar Dimension table that would aid in reporting weekly / monthly /quarterly reports. I am confused on how to return days remaining in the FISCAL_QUARTER. Q1 spans from Feb - Apr.

Attached below is the code I have been writing to generate the dates projecting 14 years in the future.

```
--Set the start date and number of years to produce
SET START_DATE = '2012-01-01';
SET NUMBER_DAYS = (SELECT TRUNC(14 * 365));

--Set parameters to force ISO
ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = 1, WEEK_OF_YEAR_POLICY = 1;

  WITH CTE_MY_DATE AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), $START_DATE) AS MY_DATE
    
      FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>$NUMBER_DAYS))  -- Number of days after reference date in previous line
  )
  SELECT 
        MY_DATE::date
        ,YEAR(MY_DATE) AS YEAR
        ,MONTH(MY_DATE) AS MONTH
        ,MONTHNAME(MY_DATE) AS MONTH_ABBREVIATION
        ,DAY(MY_DATE)
        ,DAYOFWEEK(MY_DATE)
        ,WEEKOFYEAR(MY_DATE)
        ,DAYOFYEAR(MY_DATE)
        ,YEAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE_TRUNC('month', MY_DATE),11)) AS FISCAL_YEAR
        ,CONCAT('Q', QUARTER(ADD_MONTHS(DATE_TRUNC('month', MY_DATE),11))) AS FISCAL_QUARTER
        ,MONTH(ADD_MONTHS(DATE_TRUNC('month', MY_DATE),11)) AS FISCAL_MONTH
        
    
  FROM CTE_MY_DATE
;
```

Comment: Can you add sample inputs and desired results?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I just need a field under the alias of DAYS_LEFT_IN_QUARTER, that contains the number of days between the MY_DATE and last day of every quarter.

Comment: Ok. Now give me a specific example with input and output.

Comment: A word of warning: Sequences do not necessarily generate numbers consecutively so this sql `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), $START_DATE) AS MY_DATE` may skip dates. That's why you'll see in some examples they use `ROWNUM over (order by seq4())` instead. Just realised that Simeon mentioned this :) but worth saying twice as it's super important!

Answer (score 1):

firstly your generator will get gaps, as `SEQx()` function are allowed to have gaps, so you need to use `SEQx()` as the OVER BY of a ROW_NUMBER like so:

```
WITH cte_my_date AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ4()), $START_DATE) AS my_date
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>$NUMBER_DAYS))  -- Number of days after reference date in previous line
)
```

and days left in quarter, is the day truncated to quarter, +1 quarter, date-diff in days to day:

```
,DATEDIFF('days', my_date, DATEADD('quarter', 1, DATE_TRUNC('quarter', my_date))) AS days_left_in_quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this? You can copy/paste the code straight into snowflake to test.

Using last_day() tends to make it look a little tidier :-)

```
WITH CTE_MY_DATE AS (
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), current_date()) AS MY_DATE
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>300)))
SELECT 
    MY_DATE::date
    ,YEAR(last_day(my_date,year)) AS FISCAL_YEAR
    ,concat('Q',quarter(my_date)) AS FISCAL_QUARTER
    ,datediff(d, my_date,  last_day(my_date,quarter))  AS 
DAYS_LEFT_IN_QUARTER
FROM CTE_MY_DATE
```

[image]